# Safely edit fstab and passwd files

Tags: fstab, passwd-file

I remember hearing that there were wrapper tools to help editing `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/passwd` to do basic syntax checking (eg a newline at the end of the file).

My google-fu isn't turning them up... what are their names?

Comment: For /etc/password (and /etc/shadow) there is pwck, for fstab I don't know any.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of `sudoedit`, but that does NO syntax checking.

Comment: Perhaps I was thinking of [`visudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/visudo.man.html) which does do syntax checking. Also [`vipw`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw) for the password, group, shadow-password or shadow-group file.